# Deploying Strapi.io to Heroku getting [ERR_INVALID_URL]

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, npm, strapi

I'm deploying strapi to heroku but getting a invalid url even i followed the documentation of the [strapi.io](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/deployment.html#heroku)

here is my logs

```
2020-01-29T15:32:54.185547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-01-29T15:32:56.661385+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-01-29T15:32:56.661405+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapiproject@0.1.0 start /app
2020-01-29T15:32:56.661408+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi start
2020-01-29T15:32:56.661410+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-01-29T15:32:58.561874+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29T15:32:58.560Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-01-29T15:32:58.563363+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-01-29T15:32:58.563Z] error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: http://undefined:undefined
2020-01-29T15:32:58.563366+00:00 app[web.1]: at onParseError (internal/url.js:257:9)
2020-01-29T15:32:58.563368+00:00 app[web.1]: at new URL (internal/url.js:333:5)
2020-01-29T15:32:58.563370+00:00 app[web.1]: at new URL (internal/url.js:330:22)
2020-01-29T15:32:58.563372+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/core/bootstrap.js:375:29)
2020-01-29T15:32:58.563374+00:00 app[web.1]: at Strapi.load (/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:381:11)
2020-01-29T15:32:58.563376+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Strapi.start (/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:224:7)
2020-01-29T15:32:58.578108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-01-29T15:32:58.578677+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-01-29T15:32:58.580772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! strapiproject@0.1.0 start: `strapi start`
2020-01-29T15:32:58.581113+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-01-29T15:32:58.581578+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-01-29T15:32:58.581775+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the strapiproject@0.1.0 start script.
2020-01-29T15:32:58.581960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-01-29T15:32:58.593798+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-01-29T15:32:58.594034+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-01-29T15:32:58.594423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-01-29T15_32_58_583Z-debug.log
2020-01-29T15:32:58.682466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-01-29T15:32:58.662766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-01-29T15:33:00.541839+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-peak-28060.herokuapp.com request_id=716a3aa3-ed3a-4429-880d-f04b4fb04b91 fwd="203.189.116.189" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-01-29T15:33:02.026655+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-peak-28060.herokuapp.com request_id=459549bb-6f30-444a-9f19-e45549a5a655 fwd="203.189.116.189" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I installed strapi on mysql database and i deploy it using [JawsDB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb) and also followed it documentation. Anyone know whats causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks coming from https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi/lib/core/bootstrap.js#L375

If I check the code it's this following stuff:

```js
const adminPath = _.get(
  strapi.config.currentEnvironment.server,
  'admin.path',
  'admin'
);

strapi.config.admin.url = new URL(adminPath, strapi.config.url).toString();
```

Can you please verify your `admin` value in `./config/environments/production/server.json`